# \widehat behavior when mixed with multiple subscripts

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

I was wondering whether it is possible, for a situation like the one below, to get the widehat to cover the superscript "2" but also for the two subscripts "X,Y" to be positioned right on the side of "T" with no gap.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
\widehat{T}^2_X\qquad\widehat{T^2_X}\qquad\widehat{T^2_{X,Y}}\qquad\widehat{T^2}_{X,Y}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

Essentially I am looking for something like the third symbol, where the widehat does not extend over "Y" as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which TeX distribution do you employ, and when was it last updated? The reason I ask is that I am unable to reproduce the screenshot you posted on my system (MacTeX2021, all updates applied). In particular, in the case of `\widehat{T^2_{X,Y}}`, the "hat" extends easily over the entire formula.

Comment: I use TeX Live 2020, but I also reproduced at overleaf. That's right, it does extend over the whole formula but that is what I try to avoid!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide the size of the subscript, then compensate for it outside (here I just used `\quad` rather than an exact measurement)

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
\widehat{T^2_{\mathrlap{X,Y}}}\quad + Q
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Some measuring is necessary:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\NewDocumentCommand{\WH}{m e{^_}}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}{% no subscript
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{% no superscript
      \widehat{#1}%
    }{% superscript
      \widehat{#1^{#2}}%
    }%
  }{% subscript
    \WHdo{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\WHdo}{mmm}{\mathpalette\WHdo@{{#1}{#2}{#3}}}
\newcommand{\WHdo@}[2]{\WHdo@@#1#2}
\newcommand{\WHdo@@}[4]{%
  % measure without the wide hat
  \sbox0{$\m@th#1#2\IfValueT{#3}{^{#3}}_{#4}$}%
  % measure without the subscript
  \sbox2{$\m@th#1#2\IfValueT{#3}{^{#3}}$}%
  % output with a zero width subscript
  \widehat{#2\IfValueT{#3}{^{#3}}_{\mathrlap{#4}}}
  % fix the spacing
  \kern\dimexpr\wd0-\wd2\relax
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\WH{T}^{2}_{X,Y}+x \\
T^{2}_{X,Y}+x \\
\WH{T}_{X,Y}+x \\
T_{X,Y}+x \\
\textstyle \WH{T}^{2}_{X,Y}+x \\
\textstyle T^{2}_{X,Y}+x \\
\WH{a}^{2}_{X,Y}+x \\
a^{2}_{X,Y}+x
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]